# Windows server 2008/glassfish/postgres proxy timeout HTTP idle after 120 seconds

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, postgresql, glassfish

**Environment:**

Windows 2008 Server Edition

Netbeans 6.7.1

Glassfish 2.1

Apache 2.2.15 for win32

**Original problem (almost fixed):**

The HTTP/1.1 GET method to send data fails if I wait for more than 30 seconds.

**What I did:**

I added to the http.conf file of Apache these lines:

```
#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 9000

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On
```

I went to the Glassfish panel (*localhost:4848*) and in *Configuration > HTTP services* and I put:

Timeout request: 9000 seconds (it was 30)

Standby time: -1 (it was 30 seconds)

**Problem:**

I am not able to put for glassfish a timeout bigger than 2 minutes to send a GET method.

I found this article [about glassfish settings](https://blogs.oracle.com/binublog/entry/glassfish_tuning_http_connection_queue), but i'm not able to find WHERE I should put those parameters, and if they could work.

Can anybody help try to set this timeout to a higher limit?
Maybe it's even a different setting?

**New tried solution:**

I went to the glassfish panel control, and to *Configuration > Subprocesses > "Thread-pool-name"* and changed the idle timeout from 120 seconds to 1200 seconds. Then I restarted the glassfish service (both from the administrative tools and from asadmin), but still it waits 120 seconds to go idle.
I even tried restarting the whole server, still no results. Maybe some setting in postgres? Or the connection of netbeans to postgres through glassfish?

**New finding:**

I've been searching on the internet and maybe it could be a proxy timeout, but i don't really now how to change it: can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

in the end it was the *ProxyTimeout* directive in the httpd.conf file of Apache.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout